# RPM subpackages are not built on centos 8

Tags: centos, rpm, packaging

I have a tool `mypackage` with 2 subpackages `foo` and `bar`. On centos 7, everything is fine, the two packages `mypackage-foo` and `mypackage-bar` are built. On centos 8 there is only one package `mypackage` that is built twice.
My spec file looks like :

```bsh
%global _rpmfilename %%{NAME}-%%{VERSION}-%%{RELEASE}.%%{ARCH}.rpm

Name: mypackage
Version: 1
Release: 0
Summary: -
%description

%package foo
Summary: foo 
%description foo
---

%package bar
Summary: bar
%description bar
----

%build
make

%install
make install

%files foo 
/usr/bin/foo

%files bar
/usr/bin/bar
```

At the end of the output of the command `rpmbuild -bb my-package.spec`, there are the lines :

```bsh
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/mypackage-1-0.el8.x86_64.rpm
Wrote: /root/rpmbuild/RPMS/mypackage-1-0.el8.x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: It works for me. I am sure you are actually using different spec file, because this file does not work at all (missing license and Makefile because of no source). I bet you have some conditions in the spec file and they are the culprit.

Comment: You are right, I started from scratch and the problem comes from the first line of the spec file that I forgot to write: I redefined _rpmfilename (I have updated the spec file in the initial question). It was a mistake but I  wonder how it could work on centos 6...

Comment: Likely because such macro is not used by rpmbuild (yet).